# What is the correct way to determine `ticks` from clock `freq` while avoiding overflow in C on a microcontroller?

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, real-time, integer-overflow

What is the correct way to multiply and divide ints in C to avoid overflow?  I want to determine how many `ticks` of a timer running at `freq` (in Hz) will take to make a `delay` (in ms).  This should be `ticks = freq * delay / 1000`.

But, that line looks dangerous to me.  If we write `(freq * delay) / 1000` we run the risk of overflow.  If instead we write `freq * (delay / 1000)`, we will get into floats - which are unnecessary and error prone, esp. on a microcontroller.

What is the correct way to do this?

---

Code is running on a Cortex M4 ARM microcontroller.  Ticks are from SysTick timer.  All vars are `uint32_t` or `volatile uint32_t`.

Comment: On a uC why not create a tick timer, that runs at say 100 hz, use that interrupt to increment a tick count? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: You need to consider `freq` and `delay` maximum ranges and use appropriate int size for the multiplication. For example, if `freq` and `delay` are both 16-bit, You cast them to 32-bit ints for multiplication.
If You are able to have constant `freq`, you can use it to Your advantage to simplify the computation.

Comment: Choose the more appropriate integer range for the presumed maximum count, then use **casting** to force calculation. I.e. `unsigned int ticks = (unsigned int)((unsigned long long)freq * (unsigned long long)delay / 1000ULL)`. This example should fit your calculation.

Comment: `freq/1000*delay + freq%1000*delay/1000`

Comment: Can you please, at least, if not showing actual code, specify how, or some context in which you are geting those ticks.  Are you in an embedded context?  are you running some high level operating system (one with an interrupt based clock) or are you running an Operating System with system calls to get the time?  What is the  type you are using to hold those timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested:

```
freq * (delay / 1000)
```

Is *not* a floating point operation.  That would require:

```
freq * (delay / 1000.0)
```

But you are correct that it is not necessary.  Far better would be:

```
(freq / 1000) * delay
```

So long as `freq` is a multiple of 1000, that will result in no loss of precision, and avoids at least a "premature" overflow (i.e. an overflow that occurs at lower values due to a poor choice of operation order).

An overflow of course remains possible, but this expression gives the maximum range possible for `delay` without resorting to a larger type.  For example if the expression is of type `uint32_t`, `delay` can be up to 2<sup>32</sup>/1000, or nearly 72 minutes.

Critically, the reordering enables the range of `delay` to be deterministic across any system.  It is no longer dependent on the value of `freq` - it will always be 72 minutes.

If 72 minutes is not long enough, you might even then consider a lower resolution delay (whole seconds for example) before resorting a larger data type (which will be less efficient and may add atomicity issues).  Long delays seldom require millisecond precision, and your clock may not be millisecond precise over that length of time in any case - even TCXO's are accurate to typically 2ppm, giving a potential 1ms drift after 500 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, think how long maximum delay you can have.

If using 32bit unsigned number (negative numbers for delay are not very practical because I do not know how to have a negative delay which would take us back in time). The maximum uint32_t is 4,294,967,295 which is enough for more than one hour delay.

If you set your timer to increment every 1/1000 sec then uint32_t will be enough to delay `49.7102696181` days

If you need more use a larger unsigned integer in your calculations: `((uint64_t)freq * delay) / 1000`

Comment: This can give incorrect results, because you may get overflow in the intermediate calcs.

Comment: @SRobertJames where? BTW unsigned numbers do not overflow

Comment: It is true that 2^32 milliseconds is >49 days, but that is not what the question is about.  The intermediate multiply is the issue.  Reordering helps make it deterministic (i..e. not dependent on the variable), but an overflow will still occur at ~72 minutes.  Which is probably fine in most cases.

Comment: _"unsigned numbers do not overflow"_ is somewhat semantic sophistry.  I would call it overflow, and it is largely understood.  Even if you correctly refer to it as a modulo-n error, it is still an error.

Answer (score 0):

> to determine how many ticks of a timer running at freq (in Hz) will take to make a delay (in ms). This should be `ticks = freq * delay / 1000`.

- Use sufficiently width enough math, perhaps `uint64_t` to prevent multiplication overflow.
- Consider *unsigned* math in this case to simplify rounding.
- Physical quantities often deserve a rounded answer.  Round by adding 1/2 the denominator before division.
- Clearly identify physical units.
- Avoid naked magic numbers.

```
uint32_t ticks(uint32_t freq /* Hz */, uint32_t delay /* ms */) {
  #define ms_PER_s 1000
  return (uint32_t) (( (uint64_t)freq*delay + ms_PER_s/2) / ms_PER_s);
}
```